# Best way to combine Singles in RxJava2 on Android?

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

I am new to RxJava and wondering if there is a more idiomatic way of accomplishing what the method shown below does.

```
private Flowable<String> fetchTopMovies(Context context, @IntRange(from = 1) int firstPage, @IntRange(from = 1) int lastPage) {
    checkArgument(firstPage > 0, "first page must be at least 1");
    checkArgument(lastPage > 0, "first page must be at least 1");
    checkArgument(lastPage >= firstPage, "last page cannot be less than first page");

    JsonFetcher jsonFetcher = JsonFetcher.getInstance(context);
    Flowable<String> mergedJsonsFlowable = Flowable.empty();

    for (int page = 0; page <= lastPage; page++) {
        String url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?" +
                "api_key=4&" +
                "language=en-US&" +
                "page=" + page;

        Single<String> jsonSingle = jsonFetcher.fetchJson(url);
        mergedJsonsFlowable = mergedJsonsFlowable.mergeWith(jsonSingle);
    }

    return mergedJsonsFlowable;
}
```

As you can see I am simply collecting Singles and combining them into a Flowable by hand. Is there a better way to do this without "breaking the chain"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the perfect use case for a `Flowable.range()` :

```
private Flowable<String> fetchTopMovies(Context context, @IntRange(from = 1) int firstPage, @IntRange(from = 1) int lastPage) {
   ...
   JsonFetcher jsonFetcher = JsonFetcher.getInstance(context);

   return Flowable.range(0, lastPage)
     .map(i ->  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated?" +
       "api_key=4&" +
       "language=en-US&" +
       "page=" + i)
     .flatMapSingle(url -> jsonFetcher.fetchJson(url));
}
```